# If strings of two dataframes match print rowname

Tags: r, grepl

I want to print the rownames of a dataframe as vector if it matches a string of another dataframe.

I made a thesaurus with synonyms that looks like this

```
                     Synonym                        Synonym2            Synonym3
0010                      01                      beobachten                   U
0030                     hkp                            <NA>                <NA>
0040                     hkp                            <NA>                <NA>
0050                    <NA>                            <NA>                <NA>
0060                    <NA>                            <NA>                <NA>
0065                    <NA>                            <NA>                <NA>
0070                    vipr                            perk                <NA>
0080           oberfl anästh                          anästh                <NA>
0090                vest inj                        vest inj       inj sept blau
0100                      l1                            <NA>                <NA>
0110                    <NA>                              üz                <NA>
0120                    <NA>                            <NA>                <NA>
1000       gezeigt zu achten                       putzdruck                 mhu
```

and I have a second dataframe:

```
PKV_clean
   ID     Aufzeichnungen
1   1       scharfkantig
2   1                  t
3   1  aht  36 üz distal
4   1     seit paartagen
5   1            36 vipr
6   1              perk 
7   1        üz bilfuird
8   1                   
9   1                   
10  1           knirscht
11  1   schiene empohlen
12  1            meldet
```

and it should print the rownames of the thesaurus when matching any string of a row (Synonym) with the second dataframe.

For example it should print (0070,0110) because Synonym "vipr" of 0070 and Synonym2 "üz" of 0110 matches with the second dataframe.

I tried it with:

```
#Sure things
a <- thesaurus[grep(PKV_clean$Aufzeichnungen,rownames(thesaurus))]
```

but this didn't work.

I have also tried creating a separate number for each case and create a 0|1 matrix. This works fine but with over 500 entries this is a lot of manual work.

```
PKV$"0070" = 0
PKV$"0070"[grepl("vipr | perk",PKV$Aufzeichnungen)] = 1

PKV$"0110" = 0
PKV$"0110"[grepl("üz",PKV$Aufzeichnungen)] = 1

output <- PKV|>
  select(where(is.numeric)) |> 
  select(where(~ sum(.) > 0)) |>
  names()
```

Thank you for your help!

@Mohammed Desouky
if I use the hole Dictionary with your code I get as output:
[image: The output]

Edit 2:

````
dput(head(thesaurus , 40))  
structure(list(Synonym = c("01", "hkp", "hkp", NA, NA, NA, "vipr", 
"oberfl anästh", "vest inj", "l1", NA, NA, "gezeigt zu achten", 
NA, NA, NA, "pzr", NA, "duraphat aufgetragen", NA, "bmf blutstillung", 
NA, "fllg", "f1", "f2", "f2 sät", "f3", "mdv", "f4", NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, "st", NA, "metallprimer oberfläche", NA, NA), 
    Synonym2 = c("beobachten", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "perk", "anästh", 
    "vest inj", NA, NA, NA, "putzdruck", NA, NA, NA, "psi sbi api", 
    NA, "empfindliche stelle aufgetragen", NA, "cp", NA, "fllng", 
    NA, "fllng 2", "tetric flow", "fllg 3", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "monobond plus behandelt", NA, NA), Synonym3 = c("U", 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "inj sept blau", NA, NA, NA, 
    "mhu", NA, NA, NA, "dentalhygiene", NA, "üz", NA, "blutstillung", 
    NA, "f1", NA, "fllg 2", NA, "fllng 3", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Synonym4 = c(NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "cx pulpennah", NA, NA, NA, "gezeigt", 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "duraphat", NA, "bmf", NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
    ), Synonym5 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "infiltration", 
    NA, NA, NA, "pat gezeigt", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "visco gel", 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA), Synonym6 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, "injektion", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Synonym7 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, "infil", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Synonym8 = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), Synonym9 = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_)), row.names = c("0010", 
"0030", "0040", "0050", "0060", "0065", "0070", "0080", "0090", 
"0100", "0110", "0120", "1000", "1010", "1020", "1030", "1040", 
"2000", "2010", "2020", "2030", "2040", "2050", "2060", "2070", 
"2080", "2090", "2100", "2110", "2120", "2130", "2150", "2160", 
"2170", "2180", "2190", "2195", "2197", "2200", "2210"), class = "data.frame")```

Can you work with this?
````

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
Synonym <- c()
for(i in 1:nrow(PKV_clean)){
    s <- gsub("\\s+" , "|" , PKV_clean$Aufzeichnungen[i])
    if(nchar(s) > 1){
    ind <- rowSums(sapply(thesaurus , \(x) grepl(s , x)
        ))
    } else ind <- rep(0 , nrow(thesaurus))
    a <- which(ind >= 1)
    if(length(a) > 0) ans <- toString(rownames(thesaurus)[a]) else ans <- ""
    Synonym <- c(Synonym , ans)
}

PKV_clean$Synonym <- Synonym
```

- output

```
   ID    Aufzeichnungen Synonym
1   1      scharfkantig        
2   1                 t        
3   1 aht  36 üz distal    0110
4   1    seit paartagen        
5   1           36 vipr    0070
6   1              perk    0070
7   1       üz bilfuird    0110
8   1                          
9   1                          
10  1          knirscht        
11  1  schiene empohlen        
12  1            meldet
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work as exspected with the hole dictionary. Behind the rows containing a match it prints a right answer, but behind the other rows it prints every number of the dictionary in the added synonym. I will edit my question so you can see it. But thank you very much for your effort

Comment: Would you edit your post and add `dput(head(thesaurus , 40))` so i can try the code with bigger dictionary ?

Comment: I really hope this helps @Mohamed Desouky! There are not that much values in this thesaurus. For most entries it's empty. This is the first step to make a clear allocation. The idea behind this is to make "sure things" clear and in a next step to measure string similarity between my thesaurus und for example if "vipr" is written "viepr" so that I can assign this with a certain probability to the number "0070"  Thank you very much!